# bacon.js Bus.plug: Uncaught Error: not an Observable : [object Object]

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

I was trying baconjs's tutorial.
https://baconjs.github.io/tutorials.html#content/tutorials/2_Ajax

But, I got the error at "Bus.plug"

```
var cart = ShoppingCarEt([])
var cartView = ShoppingCartView(cart.contentsProperty)
var newItemView = NewItemView()
cart.addBus.plug(newItemView.newItemStream)
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: not an Observable : [object Object]
shopBundle.js:145 assertObservable
shopBundle.js:2650 Bus.plug
```

I use follows

- baconjs@0.7.53
- jquery@2.1.3
- bacon-jquery-bindings@0.2.8
- webpack 1.7.3

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

---

#### Edit: 2015/3/25

Cause is that newItemView.newItemStream is not Observable.
(`newItemView.newItemStream instanceof Bacon.Observable` returns false.)

And newItemView.newItemStream is EventStream

```
EventStream {takeUntil: function, sampledBy: function, combine: function, flatMapLatest: function, fold: function…}
```

**Isn't all EventStream an Observable?**

I have made newItemStream as follows:

```
var $button = $('#addButton');
var $nameField = $('#nameText');
var newItemProperty = Bacon.$.textFieldValue($nameField);
var newItemClick = $button.asEventStream('click');
var newItemStream = newItemProperty.sampledBy(newItemClick);
```

---

**Following is work fine. It was my miss when first time question.**

/* And, I try more simple code. It has same error. */

```
 var someStream = Bacon.interval(1000).map(function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
});
var bus = new Bacon.Bus();
bus.log();
bus.plug(someStream);
```

---

Comment: I created this JSFiddle and the latter example code seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/opqrr02u/

Comment: The error implies that `newItemView.newItemStream` is not an Observable. Have you verified it's type using dev tools?

Comment: I tried again letter example, and it work fine. I can't reproduce the problem. I'm very sorry. Thank you very much @JJuutila .

Comment: @OlliM Thank you. I have verified ```newItemView.newItemStream```. It is EventStream, but it isn't instance of Observable. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by "bacon-jquery-bindings"(https://www.npmjs.com/package/bacon-jquery-bindings)

```
var Bacon = require('baconjs');
var $ = jQuery  = require("jquery");
Bacon.$ = require("bacon-jquery-bindings"); <-
```

It seems to overwrite asEventStream function.

We should use "bacon.jquery"(https://www.npmjs.com/package/bacon.jquery)