# What is the best way to detect if an Object is an instance of a Stream Class?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, bacon.js

Is there a way to detect if an object is an instance of a stream -class? For example RxJS or Bacon.js stream.

What I'm looking for is something like

```
function isStream(obj) {
   // if obj is RxJS or Bacon Stream return true, otherwise false
}
```

What is the most reliable way of doing this?

Comment: What do you need this for? This seems to be more a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: When you are creating UI which is reactive it can get values in different formats, like a reactive UI which can get text, object or stream like this http://jsfiddle.net/8j6edrp9/

Comment: Just let it always take a stream. Even if it's a constant stream. Also you mostly don't want arbitrary objects anyway. Try to distinguish between stream objects, arrays of other items, and primitive strings (text).

Comment: No, the problem is how to detect if it is stream or not, it may be a promise, text, HTML or some other object - how to detect if it is a stream is important here. I'm looking for a generic answer to the question, not specific answer to some other problem

Comment: Have you already tried the instanceof operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: @smendola sort of, the question is, what should you be asking with "instanceof", the Bacon in the global scope is an object, so you can't use that, I have not yet found what is the constructor to be used

Comment: It could be instanceof Bacon.Observable or instanceof Bacon.Property, but I'm not sure which is the right way to go here, here is something related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090514/bacon-js-bus-plug-uncaught-error-not-an-observable-object-object

Comment: In my case I use it so https://github.com/xgrommx/rxfy-react/blob/master/app/app.js#L14

Comment: Observable is the base class that both EventStream and Property objects inherit from. So if you want to detect anything bacon, you could use Observable.

Comment: @OlliM Thanks! That should be the right way to go.

Comment: I still doubt that detecting bacon observables is the right architectural solution for your code. I usually try to keep everything as a observables, using `Bacon.fromPromise` to convert promises and sometimes even `Bacon.once` or `Bacon.constant` for plain values.

Comment: Yes, well that's another topic :) In short, for the usability point of view, it is important to be able to say o.h1().text("Hello"); or o.attr({ fill : "red" } ) or to change the text with object like o.attr( { fill : stream } ). Forcing to use something specific is a bit scary

Comment: As for Rx, you can't check easily, as some observables don't share same interfance: e.g `Rx.ConnectableObservable instanceof Rx.Observable === false`.

Answer (score 2):

`Observable` is the base class that both `EventStream` and `Property` objects inherit from. So if you want to detect anything bacon, you could use `Observable`.

```
function isStream(v) {
  return v instanceof Bacon.Observable
}

function test(v) {
  console.log(isStream(v))
}

test(Bacon.constant(1)) // true
test(Bacon.once(1))     // true
test(1)                 // false
```

http://jsbin.com/qugihobalu/2/edit

Comment: I copied my comment as an answer.

Comment: Good answer, RxJS detect is still missing - because I asked that too can't accept it as the right answer. The other thing is that the test only works if Bacon is defined in the environment, but that's a minor detail

Answer (score 2):

There might be better ways in each framework, e.g. a native isStream equivalent, but checking instanceof is the next best solution and works for both bacon and rxjs.

```
const isStream = x => x instanceof Bacon.Observable || x instanceof Rx.Observable;
```

Comment: seen in action with [redux-rx](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-rx/blob/master/src/isObservable.js)